# Twitter Facebook buttons in Meteor jS

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, meteor

Every time I to go my web page and see how twitter or facebook loads there buttons a few seconds (styles and etc.) So first I see text like `share on twitter` than (after 2-4 seconds) "blue" button style appears in the text.

How to load "full button" (no separately downloadable parts: text,styles..) ?

```
Template.mainPage.onRendered(function(){
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
});

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Share ?" data-count="none" data-hashtags="share" data-url="somepath" >Tweet</a></div>
```

Comment: Those social plugins use iframes, and it takes a bit to load the content. If you don’t like that, then don’t use the plugins, but simple links that open the share functionality in a new window (should be easy enough to research the specific syntax for the different networks.)

Comment: @cbroe Can I donwload there "styles" ? And put to my css

Comment: No. These iframes display content from a different domain, and you can not manipulate their content in any way.